# What will be the reflex of angle RQS?

Tags: geometry

I have: In the given figure, if RP is the incident Ray, QS is the reflected Ray and the measure of angle PQR is one third of supplement of angle QPR, then reflex Angle RQS is?

(Image)
[image]

So, what I did:
We know that , the measure of angle PQR is one third of supplement of angle QPR.
So, angle PQR = ⅓(180° -  angle QPR)
And QPR is 57° ,
So angle PQR will be ⅓×123 = 41°
And since angle of incidence = angle of reflection
=> Angle QPR = angle PQR = 57°
But we know, angle PQR is 41°
So, angle QRS = 57° - 41° = 16°
And it's reflex will be 360° - 16°

344°

But ,the answer given is 278°

What's wrong with my concepts and answer?

Comment: @mathlove How come? Can you tell me how should I proceed?

Comment: @mathlove Will you add an answer, please?

Comment: Sorry, my answer was wrong, so I've deleted it...

Comment: @mathlove No problem :) If you know the answer, you can still post it. Otherwise it's okay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The angle of incidence at $P$ is $\frac{57^\circ}{2}=28.5^\circ$ from which $\angle{OQP}=28.5^\circ$ follows.

Since $\angle{PQR}=41^\circ$, the angle of incidence at $Q$ is $90^\circ-28.5^\circ=61.5^\circ$ from which we have
$$\angle{RQS}=61.5^\circ+(61.5^\circ-41^\circ)=82^\circ$$

Therefore, the reflex of $\angle{RQS}$ equals $360^\circ-82^\circ=278^\circ$.

Comment: But how is angleTPR = angle OPQ? And angle OQP =angle UQS?

Comment: @yena shah : I've deleted my previous answer. See a new one.

Comment: Yay! Thank you so so so much! I finally got it :)

Comment: @yena shah : You are welcome:)